# Trayicon mouseEntered is not working

Tags: java, mouseenter, trayicon

I have the following problem: my mouse entered method doesn't work and I don`t know why. The mouse pressed works perfectly, only the mouseEntered not.

this is the mouse listenener:

```
MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseListener() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                jpopup.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
                jpopup.setInvoker(jpopup);
                jpopup.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("Tray Icon - Mouse clicked!");                 
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Tray Icon - Mouse entered!");                 
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Tray Icon - Mouse exited!");                 
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Tray Icon - Mouse pressed!");                 
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Tray Icon - Mouse released!");                 
            }
        };
```

and here the trayIcon:

```
trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
trayIcon.addActionListener(actionListener);
trayIcon.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

Where is the error? I don't know...

EDIT: i'm using eclipse, if that is interesting...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29

doc says it's not supported.